# Rolify: Add Expire Datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rolify

I'm pretty new to Rails, and I would like to know if there is a way to had an "expired_at" field using the gems "Rolify", so I could add a Role to an User for a while, or permanent Role if field is NULL.

I thought of adding the field into the migration :

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role

      t.datetime :expired_at     # Adding field to the "join_table"
    end
    
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

But I don't have any idea about how to "override" the methods like "add_role" or "has_role?" to take this "expired_at" field into consideration, so I could do something like :

```
room = Chat::Room.find(1)

sarah = User.find(1)
david = User.find(2)

# Today
sarah.add_role :muted, room, 7.days.from_now
david.add_role :muted, room

sarah.has_role? :muted, room     # should return true
david.has_role? :muted, room     # should return true

# A week later
sarah.has_role? :muted, room    # should return false
david.has_role? :muted, room    # should return true
```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes this hard is the gem doesn't seem to support a has_many :through  https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/pull/181. Because of that it's hard to augment the join table (like adding an expiry_date to users_roles)

Comment: I suggest trying to post your question in the gem's github issues and hopefully someone has a solution, this seems like a pretty common use case.

Comment: @JoelBlum Thanks for your response, and yes, I have opened an "issue" on the github after spending a day doing research about something like this, but still without reply, so, I will keep this post open again for few days, then delete it if still without any answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have an idea that you don't need to add `expired_at` field, you can extend `rolify` gem to append the expired time after the role name, then we can parse the expired time and check whether that role is expired or not, take a look following code:

```rb
# lib/rolify/role.rb
module Rolify
  module Role
    def add_expire_role(role_name, expire_time, resource = nil)
      expire_role_name = "#{role_name}  expire_at #{expire_time}"
      add_role(expire_role_name, resource)
    end

    def check_role(role_name, resource = nil)
      expire_roles = self.class.adapter.where(self.roles).where("roles.name LIKE ?","%#{role_name}%")
      # filter still available roles
      avail_roles = expire_roles.select do |role|
        _, expire_role_time = role.name.split("expire_at")
        expired = expire_role_time.present? && expire_role_time.to_time < Time.now
        # remove expired role
        self.class.adapter.remove(self, role.name, resource) if expired
        !expired
      end
      # return true if there's still any role
      avail_roles.any?
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/rolify.rb
Rolify.configure do |config|
 # ...
end
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "rolify", "**/*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

demo

```rb
user = User.first
user.add_expire_role :test, 1.minute.from_now
user.check_role :test # true
# 1 minute later
user.check_role :test # false

user.add_role :test
user.check_role :test # always true
# try override
user.add_expire_role :test, 1.minute.from_now
# 1 minute later
user.check_role :test # still true
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a solution, and I think I will give it a try for now, thanks a lot, didn't know we could "extend" gems like that.
Btw, I don't really think it's "clean", so I guess I will have to remove this gem, and code a role system myself. 
Thanks !